# How to sort 2D array according to column wise(ascending order) in java

Tags: java, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort the array according to column wise(ascending order).The method sortByrollNum works correctly.But in second method sortByPer the highest number print on the top.It should be print according ascending order as the first method do.I tried a lot.Can anybody help me how to fix it?

```
public static int compareStrings(String str1,String str2){
    int check=str1.compareTo(str2);
    return check;
}//RollNumCheck

public static void sortByRollNum(String [] [] arr,int currentSize){
    String minName=arr[0][0];
    String minRollNum=arr[0][1];
    String minPer=arr[0][2];
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length-1;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-j-1;i++){
            int check=compareStrings(arr[i][1], arr[i+1][1]);
            if(check>0){
                minName=arr[i+1][0];
                minRollNum=arr[i+1][1];
                minPer=arr[i+1][2];
                arr[i+1][0]=arr[i][0];
                arr[i+1][1]=arr[i][1];
                arr[i+1][2]=arr[i][2];
                arr[i][0]=minName;
                arr[i][1]=minRollNum;
                arr[i][2]=minPer;
            }//if
        }//for
    }//for
    System.out.print("\nSorted Array according to Roll Number.\n");
    printArray(arr);
}//sortByRollNum

public static void sortByPer(String [] [] arr,int currentSize){
    String minName=arr[0][0];
    String minRollNum=arr[0][1];
    String minPer=arr[0][2];
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length-1;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-j-1;i++){
            int check=compareStrings(arr[i][2], arr[i+1][2]);
            if(check>0){
                minName=arr[i+1][0];
                minRollNum=arr[i+1][1];
                minPer=arr[i+1][2];
                arr[i+1][0]=arr[i][0];
                arr[i+1][1]=arr[i][1];
                arr[i+1][2]=arr[i][2];
                arr[i][0]=minName;
                arr[i][1]=minRollNum;
                arr[i][2]=minPer;
            }//if
        }//for
    }//for
    System.out.print("\nSorted Array according to Percentage.\n");
    printArray(arr);
}//sortByPer
```

Comment: Why array sorting is not suitable for you? `Arrays.sort(testdatset, new Comparator<String[]>() {      
             @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
              return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
              }
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is in your implementation of the `compareString(String str1,String str2)` method. When you use the `String.compareTo(String)` function, it compares the two strings by converting them to Unicode values to compare. Even the `sortByRollNum()` function would not work in all cases, it was just lucky that it did.

My suggestion would be since you're comparing the Roll Numbers and Percentages, parse out the integer values and compare those. You can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to do so but the string must contain only numeric values.

About compareTo: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/